# Calculation of percentage of group count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from Namelist;
Name      Age
Sathish   25
Sathish   65
Sathish   55
Sathish   45
Sathish   35
Jana      55
Jana      25
Jana      10
Bala      55
Bala      26
```

How to get Percentage value for given format;

```
Name   Count   Percentege
Sathish  5     50%
Jana     3     30%
Bala     2     20%
```

Kindly share sql query?

Comment: Sathish - Would you like to accept on of these answers? It's been a few weeks. We put in work for you - the least you can do is accept one or comment that none of these are working for you

Comment: Dont do that on SQL (will take a very long time), use your programmation language instead.

Answer (score 10):

This is a slightly sexier version of some of the other answers - note the use of `sum(100)` to avoid the longer (and more mundane) `count(*) * 100` :)

```
select name, count(*) as count, sum(100) / total as percentage
from namelist
cross join (select count(*) as total from namelist) x
group by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This query(not tested) should work :

```
SELECT Name,
COUNT(*) AS Count,
(COUNT(*) / _total ) * 100 AS Percentege
FROM Namelist,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total
  FROM Namelist) AS myTotal
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

replace column name and try this:

```
SELECT  iName, 
    COUNT(iName) AS `Count`, 
    concat(FORMAT(((COUNT(iName) * 100) / NewPeople.iCount),2),'%') AS `Percentage`
FROM   people, (SELECT COUNT(iName) AS iCount FROM people) NewPeople 
GROUP BY iName;
```

Output:

```
Name   Count   Percentage
Sathish  5     50.00%
Jana     3     30.00%
Bala     2     20.00%
```

Comment: AVG does not produce a percentage - it produces the average !

Answer (score 1):

```
select
name,
count(name) as `count`,
count(name)/(select count(*) from namelist)*100 as pct
from namelist
group by name
```